# What is nullable type in c#?

Tags: c#

when we have to use **nullable** type in C#.net? could any one please explain with example.

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/PashuSX/NullableTypes04282006114548AM/NullableTypes.aspx

Answer (score 34):

Nullable types [(When to use nullable types)](https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/11/understanding-c-nullable-types.html) are value types that can take null as value. Its default is `null` meaning you did not assign value to it. Example of value types are int, float, double, DateTime, etc. These types have these defaults

```
int x = 0;
DateTime d = DateTime.MinValue;
float y = 0;
```

For Nullable alternatives, the defualt of any of the above is null

```
int? x = null; //no value
DateTime? d = null; //no value
```

This makes them behave like reference types e.g. object, string

```
string s = null;
object o = null;
```

They are very useful when dealing with values from database, when values returned from your table is `NULL`. Imagine an integer value in your database table that could be NULL, such can only be represented with `0` if the c# variable is not nullable - regular integer.

Also, imagine an `EndDate` column whose value is not determined until an actual time in future. That could be set to NULL in the DB but you'll need a nullable type to store that in C#

```
DateTime StartDate = DateTime.Today;
DateTime EndDate? = null; //we don't know yet
```

Answer (score 5):

> When we have to use nullable type in C#.net?

Imagine there is an integer variable `id` that represents a particular `id`.

You can store `1`,`44`,or anything else.But what if you don't know the id.You cant just store `-1` or `0`.You may be thinking to assign `null` but normally `null` cannot be assigned to value types.

```
int id=null;//error
```

`Nullable type` enable you to do this.

---

Value types like `int,double,char..` **cannot** be represented as `NULL` value.

To represent `null` in value type you must use `nullable type`..

It is denoted as a value type followed by `?`

`int? id=null;`

which is transalted to

`Nullable<int> id=new Nullable<int>();`

The default value of it a nullable type is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Nullable type is new concept introduced in C#2.0 which allow user to assingn null value to primitive data types of C# language. Important to not here is Nullable type is Structure type.

BlogPost : [**Nullable type -- Why we need Nullable types in programming language ?**](http://pranayamr.blogspot.in/2010/12/nullable-type-why-we-need-nullable.html)

Comment: Slightly inaccurate, I'd say `Nullable<T>` is a wrapper type that allows null-value (or "optional") semantics for value types.  It's not just for primatives, and assigning `null` to a nullable type is really syntactical sugar.  A `null` `Nullable<T>` is not truly `null` in the reference sense.

Comment: Please fix your grammar on Blogspot before linking it to SO. If no one can understand your explanation because of poor grammar, what's the point?

Answer (score 1):

from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.80).aspx
Nullable types are instances of the System.Nullable struct. A nullable type can represent the normal range of values for its underlying value type, plus an additional null value. For example, a Nullable<Int32>, pronounced "Nullable of Int32," can be assigned any value from -2147483648 to 2147483647, or it can be assigned the null value. A Nullable<bool> can be assigned the values true or false, or null

```
class NullableExample
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int? num = null;
        if (num.HasValue == true)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("num = " + num.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("num = Null");
        }

        //y is set to zero
        int y = num.GetValueOrDefault();

        // num.Value throws an InvalidOperationException if num.HasValue is false
        try
        {
            y = num.Value;
        }
        catch (System.InvalidOperationException e)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```