# How to work with nullable types in C# language on .net framework

Tags: c#, types

The C# language provides support for two types of data: value types and reference types. While a variable of type System.String is a reference type, a variable of type Int32 is a value type

C# provides a special data types. Which is  nullable data types. and how it's work ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238059/what-is-nullable-type-in-c

Comment: Value types can't be null. Nullable types are value types that can be null.

Comment: start here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .Net there are classes and structs. Objects of an struct-type (like Int32) cannot be null.

The nullable type can imitate a null value for this objects.

Read [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx) for more Information